# Problems using MariaDB in Docker Swarm with NFS

Tags: mariadb, docker-swarm

I have problems using MariaDB within a Docker Swarm using an nfs share. The database suddenly stops accepting new connections after fdatasync() failed. This happens randomly. Aftera  few hours or after a few days. If I remove the service and start it again, everything ist running fine. The service seems not to repair itself. But I think this error should not even occur, even if the service should heal itself. I run the database as a persistence layer for the nextcloud app.

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  nextcloud_db:
    image: mariadb:10.7.4
    #container_name: nextcloud-db
    command:
      - "--transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED"
      - "--log-bin=ROW"
      - "--innodb_read_only_compressed=OFF"
      - "--character-set-server=utf8mb4"
      - "--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
      #- "--innodb-rollback-on-timeout=ON" # Tested this but did not help
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=false
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=myrootpassword
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mymysqlpassword
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_INITDB_SKIP_TZINFO=1
    networks:
      - nextcloud

### other services for running nextcloud ###

volumes:
  db:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=<storage-server-ip>,nolock,soft,rw"
      device: ":/mnt/storage/nextcloud/db"

networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true
  nextcloud:
    driver: overlay
    # driver_opts:
    #   encrypted: "true"
```

These are the logs from the moment the db died:

```
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | 2022-06-29 19:51:17 4671 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: fdatasync() returned 5
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | 220629 19:51:17 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    |
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    |
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    |
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | Server version: 10.7.4-MariaDB-1:10.7.4+maria~focal-log
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | key_buffer_size=134217728
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | read_buffer_size=131072
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | max_used_connections=10
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | max_threads=153
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | thread_count=11
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | It is possible that mysqld could use up to
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 467995 K  bytes of memory
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    |
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | Thread pointer: 0x55d81db99108
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | terribly wrong...
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | stack_bottom = 0x7fcf10137d98 thread_stack 0x49000
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | mariadbd(my_print_stacktrace+0x32)[0x55d81b24de52]
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | mariadbd(handle_fatal_signal+0x485)[0x55d81ad282b5]
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | 2022-06-29 21:49:49 4673 [Warning] Aborted connection 4673 to db: 'nextcloud' user: 'nextcloud' host: '10.0.7.189' (Got an error reading communication packets)
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | 2022-06-29 21:49:49 4672 [Warning] Aborted connection 4672 to db: 'nextcloud' user: 'nextcloud' host: '10.0.7.189' (Got an error reading communication packets)
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | 2022-06-29 21:49:49 4674 [Warning] Aborted connection 4674 to db: 'nextcloud' user: 'nextcloud' host: '10.0.7.189' (Got an error reading communication packets)
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | 2022-06-29 22:16:02 4676 [Warning] Aborted connection 4676 to db: 'nextcloud' user: 'nextcloud' host: '10.0.7.189' (Got an error reading communication packets)
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | 2022-06-29 22:18:13 4678 [Warning] Aborted connection 4678 to db: 'nextcloud' user: 'nextcloud' host: '10.0.7.189' (Got an error reading communication packets)
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | 2022-06-29 22:24:46 4679 [Warning] Aborted connection 4679 to db: 'nextcloud' user: 'nextcloud' host: '10.0.7.189' (Got an error reading communication packets)
nc_nextcloud_db.1.1mfx9xkwd1sd@v220210169548138574    | 2022-07-01 21:49:02 7148 [Warning] Aborted connection 7148 to db: 'nextcloud' user: 'nextcloud' host: '10.0.7.189' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

I found no other logs related to the isse.

Anyone has a clue what's going on here?

Maybe the NFS share is unavailable for a few seconds and so the database has problems reading/writing? Is it possible to self-heal the mariadb service after this error occurs? There are no other problems as long as the database service is running. I can upload and delete files etc. So it is not a permissions issue on the nfs share.

Further MariaDB metrics:
https://jpst.it/2TX-F

Host system info:

```
Docker node VM with Ubuntu:
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
2 vCPUs
8 GB RAM
160 GB SSD System-Storage (Raid 10)
```

Comment: Running a Release Candidate (MariaDB 10.7.1) is a likely DEADLY situation to find yourself in.  Installing any release less than 90 days old is a questionable decision.  Do you have the time to report a problem, hope for a resolution and likely wait for a corrective action many days?  Leave that to someone else and NEVER be the EARLY ADOPTER unless you are already DEAD in the WATER with no HOPE of getting on line.  Use Google search for  mariadb 10.7.1 changelog to determine release status for the version.  Use an older mature version with at least 90 days in the wild as a STABLE VERSION.

Comment: I already updated to 10.7.4 which is stable. The error persists. I accidentally added the wrong logs (updated)

Comment: Excellent move up in version.  Even if it is only about 60 days STABLE. Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I added additional host and mysql/mariadb information at the end of my question

Comment: Thanks for posting data.  Analysis in process.  Hope to have observations posted in about 36 hours.

Comment: Additional information request.  Please post TEXT A) complete my.cnf B) From OS report of ulimit -a  (to reveal OS liimits being used).  Do you have flexibility to use SKYPE TALK in English?  Could conserve much time.

Comment: Could you post your code used to 'Connect", 'Process', 'Close' client initiated requests to your MariaDB?

Comment: Suggestions/observations will be more specific if you will post Additional information requested on 7/6/2022. Thank you.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I added new information to the justpaste document. Skype Talk in English would be possible. Can I send you my Skype details via Email to the mail adress listed on your profile here on stackoverflow?

Comment: @WilsonHauck I assume you were not able to track issue down further?

Comment: You may have missed this request.  Could you post your code used to 'Connect", 'Process', 'Close' client initiated requests to your MariaDB?  Please do send your Skype ID via email to me.

Comment: When we can connect and TALK, we will review your 7/6/2022 Show Full ProcessList for 10 minutes, minimum.  If your time permits.  Thank you, Wilson Hauck

Comment: I am using the official nextcloud image so the code for Database Connections is available in the nextcloud GitHub repo. Or do you mean something else? I don't use any special code for the database connection. I send you my Skype ID. Just PM me there if you have some spare time. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just post your Skype ID here.  Mine in  wlhauck@aol.com

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support mounting NFS to initialize data

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Works for me without problems on other systems without Docker Swarm.

Comment: @NKnuelle Recommended reference:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/disk-issues.html